# ShowWindow doesn't work when a window is running under SYSTEM account

Tags: delphi, winapi, showwindow

I'm currently using this code to restore a minimized window, and it works perfectly when I try to restore a window that runs under my own user account.

```pascal
ShowWindow(wHandle, SW_RESTORE);
```

The problem arises when I try to restore a window that runs under the SYSTEM account.  I found out that `ShowWindow()` always returns a false value to me. Also, in my manifest, I have tried setting it to both "Requires Administrator" and "As Invoker", but it still yields the same result.

Is there another function that works similarly to `ShowWindow()` and is able to restore a window that is running under the SYSTEM account?

Comment: You may have to [ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changewindowmessagefilterex), though running a GUI application under the local SYSTEM account on random users' desktops is probably the real problem you need to solve. There doesn't seem to be a convincing reason to do this. What problem is that trying to solve?

Comment: I'm actually writing a program to help me call an external application and if the application is already running, I would like to restore the window and bring it forward. But the problem that I'm facing is that the external application tend to run on SYSTEM instead on my own username.

Comment: Run your application under system account and it will work. Probably the way to design such a solution is to write a Windows service running under the system account and write a front end GUI application sending commands to the service.

Comment: @IInspectable only the process that created the target window can call `ChangeWindowMessageFilter/Ex()` for itself.  You can't call that for someone else's window. "*running a GUI application under the local SYSTEM account on random users' desktops is probably the real problem you need to solve*" - agreed.

Comment: Low privilege processes are blocked from various interactions with high privilege processes for security reasons.

Comment: @fpiette okay, I'll try it out. Thank you for the guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a thread with "local system" privileges in the user application. Then execute your `ShowWindow` in the thread.

Some steps:

1. Program sends session ID to service
2. Service calls `OpenProcessToken` and `DuplicateTokenEx` to create a
   Local System token
3. Service calls `SetTokenInformation` to change the token session ID to
   match the program's
4. Service calls `DuplicateHandle` to create handle to the token
5. Service sends handle to program
6. Program calls `SetThreadToken` using the received handle

Refer: [Run process as Local System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43411059/run-process-as-local-system)

For the @fpiette's comment, [Interacting with a User from a Service Indirectly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services#interacting-with-a-user-from-a-service-indirectly) shows more details.